# iOS initialise view programmatically without constraining the position

Tags: ios, autolayout, constraints

Here is my problem, I have a scroll view `scrollExerciseIndex` that I use only as a scrolling bar, in this scroll view I place a UIView `indexesView` and I want it to be always at the center of the scroll view. For this I use layout constraints :

`UIView * indexesView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(xPosition, 0, dimension*numberIndexes, dimension)];
    [self.scrollExerciseIndex addSubview:indexesView];
    [self.scrollExerciseIndex setContentSize:CGSizeMake(dimension*numberIndexes, dimension)];
    if (xPosition != 0) {
        NSLayoutConstraint * xCenterConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:indexesView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.scrollExerciseIndex attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX multiplier:1.0 constant:0];
        [self.scrollExerciseIndex addConstraint:xCenterConstraint];
    }`

Here is the expected result :
[image]

Don't pay attention to all the element, just the bar at the bottom of the screen is my problem.

I have to create view programmatically because sometimes I will activate the constraints, sometimes not and I have to set the frame of the view dynamically. So for now I initialise the view `indexesView` like so : 
`UIView * indexesView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(xPosition, 0, dimension*numberIndexes, dimension)];`
 (I know, not very original)

I would like to know if there is a way to initialize the view programmatically but to say to auto-layout that it has no constraints on the position because right now if the screen turns in landscape mode there is a conflict as the scrollview's frame changes so the distance between the center of the scroll view (on which I set a constraint) and the position of the subview's frame (xPosition) is no longer the same.
[image]
As you can see, the view is no longer at the center of the scroll view and I have some constraints broken.

> Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
>   NSLayoutConstraint:0x7bed6c50 UIView:0x7bed6ad0.centerX == UIScrollView:0x7e273200.centerX

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What exactly is the issue you are encountering ?

Comment: Thanks for your quick reaction, here I have put new screen shots as I realised the other one didn't explain much

Comment: Can you add the entire code, including the one that creates the scroll view ?

Comment: Maybe you should [read this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2154/_index.html) too.

Comment: I have added the code to create the subviews and the setting of the scroll view's content, but the scroll view itself is created in IB

Comment: When using auto layout with `UIScrollView`, the `contentSize` is automatically managed, see the tech note from my comment above and [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25021745/center-contents-of-uiscrollview-when-using-autolayout)

Comment: Ok, I will try to look more thoroughly into it but for now, if I don't set the content size explicitly it doesn't scroll

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found what I was looking for by reading a book about Audio-Layout.
My problem was that audio layout would create constraints behind my back automatically. When using AutoLayout a type of constraints is created from non-autoLayout specifications (The used to describe interface when auto layout didn't exist). So constraints are created using the initial frame of the view. The only thing I had to do was :

```
[indexesView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
```

to disable this creation of constraints from the frame, and then recreate explicitly the constraints for `width` and `height` if needed (which wasn't the case for me, but I still made the test) like so :

```
`NSLayoutConstraint * widthConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:indexesView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil attribute:0 multiplier:1.0 constant:widthValue];
 NSLayoutConstraint * heightConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:indexesView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil attribute:0 multiplier:1.0 constant:heightValue];

[indexesView addConstraint: heightConstraint];
[indexesView addConstraint: widthConstraint];`
```

When adding constraints programmatically, don't forget to call : `[indexesView setNeedsUpdateConstraints];` so the constraints are recalculated only when needed.

Last info that I read and can be useful in general, when adding a lot of constraints, the apple doc specifies that it is more efficient to use the method :
    `[myView addConstraints:(NSArray<NSLayoutConstraints *> *)]` than to call `addConstraint:` for each constraint.

Hope it can be useful to someone.